# download file with non-alphanumerical characters

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have used `window.location.href` to download the file (zip file). After downloading the file, the Japanese characters are breaking so there seems to be an encoding problem. (Actually, the zip file name is fine but the content (pdf files) have wrong characters. The actual zipfile in the server is okay. How do I encode the content of a zip?

Another problem encountered here is that while Korean and German Windows PC downloads the file correctly, only the desktop using Japanese OS is causing the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a serverside issue from before you zip your files. Your actions in JavaScript have no influence on your zip file.

Comment: This sounds like the charset used was _Shift-JIS_ instead of something like unicode. Either change your region settings for the whole of _Windows_, or use a locale emulator to run your favourite extraction/pdf software in the required encoding; https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator/releases/latest ([**details**](http://i.watashi.me/archives/locale-emulator.html))